# How can I get from an Azure DB an existing login that hasn't user asociated?

Tags: sql-server, azure, authentication

as a developer I have access to a DB, I know that exists in master a list of logins, I want to get the available logins to create users with.

Indeed, I can execute `CREATE myuser FOR LOGIN one_of_the_available_logins` but I would like to check if a login is available to raise an error

I try it with a `SELECT * FROM sys.sql_logins` but for security I have didn't allowed to use reserved keywords on schemas

Please some help!!

Answer (score 0):

We can use the below T-SQL to get the Logins and the associated Users.

```
select l.name as [login name],u.name as [user name] from sysusers u inner join sys.sql_logins l on u.sid=l.sid
```

Then, we can check if the Login user has the associated User already.

[image]

Comment: First of all, thank you, but the only inconvenient is that your answer ony run in master, I need it in own database